# When importing objects with aws s3, I get a 503 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get the following error when shooting objects from the cloud. I can't pull the objects inside the bucket:

```
string accessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string secretKey = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = "http://s3-region.teletek.net.tr:80";
IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey,
        secretKey,
        config);
ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request();
request.BucketName = "envelope";
ListObjectsV2Response response = client.ListObjectsV2(request);
foreach (Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object o in response.S3Objects)
{
   // Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", o.Key, o.Size, o.LastModified);
    listBox1.Items.Add(o.Key + o.Size + o.LastModified);
}
```

- Error Code:

```
Error making request with Error Code ServiceUnavailable and HTTP Status Code ServiceUnavailable. No further error information was returned by the service
```

Comment: `ServiceUnavailable` is the key word, and "No further error information was returned by the service" is a logical response to that. So, i do not see a problem with this behavior, except that it might not be the functionality you are looking for, but "No other information was returned by you", so one has to guess what your intentions where....

Comment: but I can shoot buckets. I cannot access only the objects in the buckets. For example, there are 2 buckets in this endpoint and I can access them in a separate method. I can only access the objects in this bucket.

Comment: Why are you setting a `ServiceURL`?

Comment: because I'm sending a request to my endpoint in the cloud. But I only get errors when shooting objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/dotnet3.5/S3/ListObjectsExample/ListObjects/ListObjects.cs

Comment: I just changed the same code you gave
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config ();
 config.ServiceURL = "http://s3-med3401.teletek.net.tr:80";
_s3Client = new AmazonS3Client (accessKey, secretKey, config); I changed the location like this but it gave the same error. How can I connect to the cloud without AccessKey and SecretKey? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?